# SQL: Struggling to join 3 tables from a many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql-server, join

I have 3 tables:

```
Users - Username
Procedures - SeriesNum,ProcNum (Composite PKey),Description,CurrentRev
UsersProcedures - Username,SeriesNum,ProcNum,RevTrained,LevelTrained,DateTrained
```

How would I query so that it shows, for each user, all the procedures, and if they are trained in those procedures, the values in the usersprocedures table (and if they're not trained, those values would come up as null because they're not present).

The closest i've got is with this query:

```
SELECT Procedures.SeriesNum,Procedures.ProcNum,Description,CurrentRev,RevTrained,LevelTrained,DateTrained,Users.Username
FROM Procedures,Users
LEFT JOIN UsersProcedures ON UsersProcedures.Username = Users.Username
```

However this doesn't work fully because the values it's pulling from the UsersProcedures table are the same for each procedure, rather than being unique to each procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-- select whatever columns you like
SELECT p.*, u*, pu.*
-- a cross join conmbines all rows from both tables 
FROM Procedures p 
CROSS JOIN Users u
-- add the exp to the mix 
LEFT JOIN UsersProcedures pu 
    ON  pu.Username = u.Username 
    AND p.SeriesNum = pu.SeriesNum  
    AND p.ProcNum = pu.ProcNum
```

Comment: That works. Thanks! I'd tried putting those last 2 Join criterion at the end of mine in my OP, however it was complaining about multi-part identifiers on those, but the Cross Join solves that.